# how to install eric python IDE and all the plugins on windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, installation, eric-ide

so, i want to learn python and looking around for python IDE, i already have PyCharm but i also want to be able to make GUI so i download eric IDE
eric IDE need these prerequisites to install

```
Python 3.1.0 or better
Python 2.6.0 or better
Qt 5.3.0 or better (from Digia)
Qt 4.10.0 or better (from Digia)
PyQt 5.3.0 or better (from Riverbank)
PyQt 4.10.0 or better (from Riverbank)
QScintilla 2.8.0 or better (from Riverbank)
```

i already download them all and able to install python 2.7 but i don't understand how to install the other, the only guide i found is only for win xp or linux.

Comment: So what didn't work with the WinXP guide?

Answer (score 2):

I just went through this process on Windows 7, so hopefully I can help you.

If you are running Windows7, get the following:

1) Python 2.7.0 link (11 was the version I used) amd64 - I got bit by this. When you follow the download link on the eric website, click on the version number instead of the download link. This will give you the option of downloading the x64 version.

2) PyQT 4.10 link -You will want to get this version if you are using python 2.7.x. There are no 5.x builds for Python 2.7. When looking to download the binaries (unless you want to compile), pay close attention to both the x64/x32 and the Py[ver] the link is for.

Note, it is important that both Python and PyQt be in sync for x32/x64 or Eric will not compile. It is also important to note that PyQt is Python version sensitive. PyQt 5.3.x is currently only built for Python 3.3.x, not Py 2.3x. PyQt 4.10.x has been built for both Py 2.7.x and Py 3.3.x

3) The Eric Zip, uncompressed, in a writable directory for the user.

Install Python first, followed by PyQt (It installs in the Python Directory), and then run the install.py from the root directory of eric. Watch the cmd window carefully since it will give you some useful information if things don't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you can get binary packages from the [PyQt4 download page](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) that will install everything except Python and Eric.

Ignore the source packages at the top of the page - scroll down to where the Windows exe installers are and make sure you pick the right one for the version of Python you want to use (2.7 or 3.4) and the platform you're on (32bit or 64bit).

You don't need any of those other downloads. Since you already seem to have Python installed, all you need to do is run the PyQt4 installer, and then run the Eric installer.

There is also a [PyQt Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) which you might find helpful if you're just getting started.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.4.4 may be a better choice than 2.7 in the long run.
For other stuff. this page may be helpful:
http://techattitude.com/tips-tricks-and-hacks/how-to-install-eric6-ide-for-python-on-windows/

Comment: It's generally better to include more than a link in an answer (in case that link goes dead). Since the cited instruction mostly consists of two steps (download pyqt5 and download eric), they could be just cited here with the link to the full article.

Answer (score -1):

It is not that easy to install eric6 on Windows 8.1 x64.

Python 3.5.1 x64 installs in \appdata\local\programs\python\python35.

Pyqt5.5.1 x64 does not detect python 3.5 and it is only built for python 3.4, and starts to drop a folder called C:\python34.

Further googling provided no help, only this stackoverflow question.

Comment: This sounds like a non-Answer. Or is it an Answer ?